# How to get data from serial port to usb on android application?

Tags: android

I'm new in android.I have android tablet,usb to serial port cable and gprs device.

The gprs device will be connected using the serial port.

So now, how can i get data from gprs device to android app using usb to serial port cable.

Please let me know.

Comment: which API version of android you are using in your project.

Comment: Did you managed it to work?